# Compare YYYYMM with date range

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question on how to compare YYYYMM in Oracle SQL.
graduation_date is saved in string format like '200212'. I want to query rows with graduation_date from Jan 2007 to Jan 2010.

Here is my query:

```
select ids,
from   table
where  to_date(substr(graduation_date,1,6),'YYYYMM' between 'Jan-2007'and 'Jan-2010'
```

I got error

> ORA-01858:a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was
>   expected

Can anyone can help figure this out? Many thanks!

I found a way to compare. Since the graduation_date is saved as vchar2  format like '20021200'.Default value is '00000000'. ONLY Year & Month is saved in Graduation_date.  Here is my query:
    select ids,
    from   table
    where  graduation_date between '20070100'and '20100100'

I tired some other ways advised but got ORA-01843: not a valid month error
          select ids,
          from   table
          where  to_date(substr(graduation_date,1,6),'YYYYMM' between 'Jan-2007'and 'Jan-2010'

Thank you guys but just wondering why I can't use to_date to compare in this scenario?

Comment: Remove the comma after ids...  Need a closing bracket after YYYYMM, is graduation_date of type char/varchar? If not then you can't do substr... Finally do to_date('200701', 'YYYYMM') and to other date also...

Comment: A date literal is written like this: `date '2007-01-01'`. Not `'Jan-2007'`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma after ids... Need a closing bracket after YYYYMM, is graduation_date of type char/varchar? If not then you can't do substr... Finally do to_date('200701', 'YYYYMM') and to other date also...

Comment: my where clause is                                                                                               where To_date(substr(d.graduation_date,1,6),'YYYYMM') between to_date('200701','YYYYMM') and to_date('201001','YYYYMM')     but got not a valid month error

Comment: Outside of your current SQL, try to fire just substr part of the sql and check if you are getting the result in YYYYMM format

Comment: the substr result is like 199908 and to_date result is lie 8/1/1999...so confused

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to delete comma here: `select ids,` and to add bracket after 'YYYYMM' here: `To_date(substr(graduation_date,1,6),'YYYYMM'` you also need to know:

1. You are seeing the dates in the format which is set in your NLS settings. Even after conversion you letting your NLS to show in already set format, in your case it's seems like MM/DD/YYYY, check by:

   `SELECT VALUE FROM nls_session_parameters WHERE parameter = NLS_DATE_FORMAT';`

if you want to select `date` in your special format then after `to_date` function also use `to_char` function, like (if your data is in that `graduation_date` column like `YYYYMM` then no need to use `substr` function, else use as below):

`SELECT to_char (to_date (SUBSTR (graduation_date, 1, 6), 'YYYYMM'), 'YYYYMM') FROM table;`

2. So, if you want to select your data, then use below script (if your data is in that `graduation_date` column like `YYYYMM` then no need to use `substr` function, else use as below):

   `SELECT ids
       FROM table
           WHERE to_date (SUBSTR (graduation_date, 1, 6), 'YYYYMM') 
   BETWEEN to_date ('200701', 'YYYYMM') AND to_date ('201001', 'YYYYMM');`
3. I don't suggest to use `'Jan-2012'` (even if you convert by `to_char` function) with `BETWEEN` cause it will compare bytes of letter, not the month, so it's possible to get also `June` or `July` for each year if you use like this (and data only for `Jan`, not all months between them):

`WHERE to_char (to_date (SUBSTR (graduation_date, 1, 6), 'YYYYMM'), 'Mon-YYYY') 
             BETWEEN 'Jan-2007' AND 'Jan-2010';`

result something like this:

`Jan-2007
 Jun-2007
 Jul-2007
 Jan-2010` ...

Comment: useful links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966274/how-to-handle-to-date-exceptions-in-a-select-statment-to-ignore-those-rows ;

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008693/oracle-to-date-incorrect-output?rq=1

Comment: I got ORA-01843: not a valid month error for following query                                              
    SELECT ids
    FROM table
        WHERE to_date (SUBSTR (graduation_date, 1, 6), 'YYYYMM') 
BETWEEN to_date ('200701', 'YYYYMM') AND to_date ('201001', 'YYYYMM');

Comment: So, for just make sure: grad_date is `varchar2` and data there is like `200701`, right?

Comment: grad_date is varchar2, default '00000000', like '19990800'. since only year and month saved, last 2 digits always 00. if I query                                              select to_date(SUBSTR (d.grad_dt, 1, 6),'YYYYMM')
from table             I got result like '8/1/1999'. but if want compare the dates, like SELECT ids FROM table WHERE to_date (SUBSTR (graduation_date, 1, 6), 'YYYYMM') BETWEEN to_date ('200701', 'YYYYMM') AND to_date ('201001', 'YYYYMM') I got error msg"NOT valid month"

Comment: I found a way : select ids, from table where graduation_date between '20070100'and '20100100' then I can get results. but just confused why to_date is not working here?

Comment: try to do like this:
`SELECT ids
    FROM table
        WHERE to_date (SUBSTR (graduation_date, 1, 6), 'YYYYMM') 
BETWEEN to_date ('200701', 'YYYYMM') AND to_date ('200702', 'YYYYMM');`
I'm afraid that maybe you have some data like: `201220` with not valid month...

Comment: I found the reason.  There were some bad data and cause the problem.

Comment: Yes, I meant this. If my suggestions worked for then please Vote and set the Green flag for the answer.